# I get a message denying access when I try to delete a file that I created

Tags: windows-7, authorization

OS client: Windows7 professional
OS server: Windows 2003

I create a new file in my documents folder (on the server). When I try to delete the file later, I get the following error:

`Cannot delete the file. You need permissions from domain\my own username to delete this file.`

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the C:\Windows\CSC folder, which is used for Offline files. I had changed some access rights there (because I had to retrieve a couple of files).

To fix it, I restarted to safe mode, removed everything from the CSC folder, then rebooted. Now it's working again. Just make sure that you have synchronized everything or that you have made a copy of the CSC folder so no files get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly can't say WHY you're getting the error without being able to dig around.  I would try removing and re-adding all rights/permissions on your My Documents folder, to make sure you don't have some wierd sub-permission set on it.

As a work-around you might also try something like Unlocker.  It may actually be that some kind of process has the file locked....

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/